# Is it good practice to use exec with PHP?

Tags: php, bash

I was looking for some PHP library to convert Docx files to PDF files and didn't find anything free and stable but I came across some good bash scripts that ran pretty well. So I was wondering if it was considered okay to use exec() or shell_exec() to run some shell script that would accomplish a task instead of coding it in PHP ? If it's not, what are de cons of this method ?

Comment: It is fine to do so, as long as you do not pass it any user input. The danger lies in the fact that a user could execute server side commands should ANY dynamic input be given to the `shell_exec()` or the `exec()` functions. As long as this is not the case, it should be fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, You can use exec() or shell_exec().
Problem is not in using these commands. The problem arises when you are going to take input from user and directly use user-input in the command without verifying the input.